# How do I stop triggering Jenkins job on approved merge request?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I use Jenkins with Gitlab plugin. I have Jenkins jobs triggering on merge request events.

- On the Gitlab webhook part, `Merge request events` is ticked :

> This URL will be triggered when a merge request is
> created/updated/merged

- On Jenkins job, I made sure `Opened Merge Request Events` is ticked and `Approved Merge Requests (EE-only)` is unticked

I looked at the environment variables that are passed to the job, such as `gitlabActionType` and `gitlabMergeRequestState` but none of them seem to indicate the event of `Approved Merge Request`. It is important for me to filter it out, there is no need to trigger a job each time a user approves a merge request.